# System.currentTimeMillis() and nanoTime() not timing correctly

Tags: android, time

Has anyone else had a problem where Android is measuring time intervals incorrectly?
On all my devices except my HUDL2 this code returns the correct amount of time: checked by running a stopwatch.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timenano = System.nanoTime();

try {
    Thread.sleep(12000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long finishnano = System.nanoTime();
long totalTime = finish-time;
long totalTimeNano = finishnano-timenano;
Log.i(TAG,"totalTime="+totalTime+", nano="+totalTimeNano/1000000);
```

Returns 12seconds, but actually takes nearer 17 seconds to run (according to a stopwatch).
Nano time and millis have the same results...

This realisation came about because a game I wrote runs slower on HUDL2

Comment: Just played another game on the HUDL2 - and noticed the same issue on Traffic Racer.  On the HUDL2 movement is slower.  I can only assume the game is also relying on the system time in some manner.

Comment: There's some information which might be useful within _SystemClock_ documentation ; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html . Still a 5 second difference sounds a bit too much.

Comment: Very weird.  Just installed the latest HUDL2 update, and the issue has gone away.  It could have just been restarting it I guess.  But hard to know.     There have been some issues reported with HUDL2's clock going wrong - maybe it's associated.

Answer (score 0):

I probably think, you have not included the code in onResume. It should be included in onResume method.